# How would one implement OCaml / F#'s "function" construct in Scala?

Tags: scala, f#, pattern-matching, ocaml

A common tendency I've discovered in Scala is something like this:

```
def someFunction(a: SomeClass) = a match { ... }
```

And from there on `a` is never used ever again. This pattern is SO common in FP that OCaml and F# have a built-in construct to let you ditch that parameter entirely.

Instead of writing this:

```
let someFunction a = 
  match a with
  | 0 -> true
  | _ -> false
```

you can simply write this:

```
let someFunction =
  function
  | 0 -> true
  | _ -> false
```

So my question is, is it possible to write something like this in Scala?

```
def someFunction = function {
  case 0 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Saving an otherwise unnecessary parameter.

I've attempted to write it as a function that takes a call-by-name parameter, but Scala won't let me make an empty `match` block.

Is it possible? Or does scala perhaps already have something like this built in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a function instead of a method:

```
val someFunction: Int => Boolean = {
  case 0 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

You have to explicitly write the type annotations, but that must not be a drawback - for API usage it is useful documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use partial functions:

```
def function[A, B](mf: PartialFunction[A, B]): A => B = x => mf(x)
```

although this requires you to specify the type of the function on the left e.g.

```
def someFunction: Int => Boolean = function {
    case 0 => true
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: I like it! It's clean and fairly concise and can be used as `function[Int, Boolean]` as well as what you suggested. I wonder what other ways of solving this issue there are

Comment: Creating a `PartialFunction` in this case doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @sschaef I'm guessing Lee just tried to match the F# code as close as possible

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - Actually I didn't think you could use this syntax with a non-partial function. Since you can there isn't any benefit to doing this, as sschaef's answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a (very ugly) way of doing it

It's more of a hack/workaround than it is an actual solution, but I figured I'd post it here anyway

You can do this:

```
def something = (_: Int) match {
  case 0 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

This works and solves the problem, but it's ugly and clunkier to write than what I tried to get away from in the first place.

I'm curious to see what you guys can come up with.